# Laravel - Eloquent model: IP address retrieved as decimal?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent model representating a table storing IP addresses. The column is of varchar type.
My problem is the IP addresses retrieved seem assumed as decimals instead of string. So value "192.168.0.1" in database is retrieved as "192". dd() returns it as number (without double quotes).

```
$data = MyModel::all();
dd($data[0]->ip_address); // "192.168.0.1" displayed as numeric 192
dd($data); // but this shows all IP addresses as string well
```

Thanks for help.

UPDATE: ip_address is primary key in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is because I put the ip_address column as primary key. The solution is adding:`public $incrementing = false;` in my model class.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign this values to your model

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = 'ip_address';

    public $incrementing = false;
}
```